# In Javascript generate a random whole number excluding array of numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a random whole number in a specific range (min, max).

But exclude any numbers in an array.

I have a function like this:

```
function randomInt(min, max) { // min and max included 
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

I want to add a 3rd parameter called something like `exclude` where I would pass in numbers like `[3, 5, 6]` and those numbers wouldn't be possible to return.

If all numbers in the range are excluded (this is a possibility in this case) then it should return false.

I was thinking of doing a while loop `while exclude.indexOf(random_number) > -1` and then generating a random number until it finds one that's not been used yet, but i'm not sure how to detect when it has exhausted all possible options and we know that every number in range is excluded.

Comment: What are the actual extreme values of `min`, `max` and `max - min` going to be? That could affect how to go about this.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Likely going to be small (0,100)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider building an array that includes the range except for the numbers in the array. If that array is 0 elements long, you have no options yet. Then, you can pick a random index of the array.

```js
function randomInt(min, max, exclude) {
   const nums = [];
   for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      if (!exclude.includes(i)) nums.push(i);
   }
   if (nums.length === 0) return false;

  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length);
  return nums[randomIndex];
}

console.log(randomInt(1, 5, [2, 3]))
```

For completeness, here's a more efficient solution that uses `Set` for the exclude list so we don't have to use the array `includes` method, which potentially causes a lot of extra iteration.

```
function randomInt(min, max, exclude) {
  const nums = [];
  const excludeLookup = new Set(exclude);
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    if (!excludeLookup.has(i)) nums.push(i);
  }
  if (nums.length === 0) return false;

  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length);
  return nums[randomIndex];
}

console.log(randomInt(1, 5, [2, 3]))
```

Comment: Not only that, you won't need to repeat any random number generation :)

Comment: `Math.random()` is inclusive of 0 but not 1. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Also you can use `Map` on exclude array to avoid, looping everytime to check the value is present on `exclude`  array or not

Comment: Really the better way would probably be to create a `Set` of the exclude numbers to gain hash table efficiency