# Efficient method for generating a unique random number that isn't in an exclusion array

Tags: javascript, random

I am making a snake game in javascript and I need a way to choose a random position for the fruit (a single number on which modulus is applied to get the x and y numbers) but the position should not overlap with positions the snake is already covering. I'm currently using recursion to do this:

```js
function random(min = 0, max = 100, exclude = []) {
  let r = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  return exclude.includes(r) ? random(...arguments) : r;
}
```

When the snake covers a large portion of the board leaving only a few spaces for the fruit, this would take a lot of cycles to return a valid number.

Is there a better method to do this or is this method good enough?

Comment: Yes, there is: replace recursion with a `while` loop and convert `exclude` into a `Set`.

Comment: Create an array of non-excluded numbers first, then randomly select an index.

Comment: Also you want `Math.floor` not `Math.round` to accurately adhere to  your range.

Comment: IMO this is an interesting sample of big-O vs. real world performance: your current algorithm is theoretically unbounded (i.e. it could loop infinitely) wheras the one suggested by Jonathan has a definite upper bound. But depending on the specific implementation either one could perform better in real-world examples.

Comment: related: [In Javascript generate a random whole number excluding array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639315/in-javascript-generate-a-random-whole-number-excluding-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of "valid" numbers and select a random member of it:

```
function random(min = 0, max = 100, exclude = []) {
    let free = []
    for (let r = min; r <= max; r++) {
        if (!exclude.includes(r))
            free.push(r)
    }
    return free[Math.floor(Math.random() * free.length)]
}
```

This way there will be no need for trial and error loops.

Comment: This creates a full array every call, surely a `while` loop with an `includes` check is faster, since it exits early.

Comment: If `min` and `max` are far apart and `exclude` is very small (or even empty) I doubt this will perform better than OP's original approach

Comment: @Mureinik: the OP provided the context, `max-min` is guaranteed to be very small.